# Does spark load whole data from cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have following code.

```
Dataset<Row> kpiDF = spark.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
.options(new HashMap<String, String>(){{put("keyspace",keyspace);put("table", table);}})
.load()
.filter("kpi='test'")
```

my question is, where this will load all the data from cassandra table and then apply filter or it will only load 'test' kpi data from cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

If column `kpi` is partition key then spark-cassandra-connector will only read corresponding records.

By default predicate pushdown is enabled.

If cassandra cannot suffice the filter condition then spark-cassandra-connector will read complete data and then apply filter.

you can check whether filter is being pushed to cassandra using `df.explain`.

[Predicate Pushdown in spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md#automatic--predicate-pushdown-and-column-pruning)